# JS simple christmas tree on one loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make one loop Christmas tree using `string.repeat` method.

```js
let Height = 6;
let Star = "*";

for (let i = 0; i < Height; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    document.write(Star);
  }
  document.write("<br>");
}
```

I've created it on 2 loops, but don't know how to do it on a single one. Thank you for help.

Comment: had you have a look to [`String#repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)?

Comment: Please show us your attempt using `string.repeat`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) method of a string:

```js
const Height = 6;
const Star = "*";

for (let i = 0; i < Height; i++) {
  document.write(`${Star.repeat(i + 1)}<br />`);
}
```